# How can I open the "Revisions" of a question when it has never been edited?

Tags: support, revision-history

I want to access the Revisions of a question to see when it became a Hot Network Question, but because it has not been edited, there is no "edited Month 00 '00 at 00:00" that I can click.

How can I open the "Revisions" of a question when it has never been edited?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to. If you click on the "clock rewinding (?)" button under the favourite button, you'll be taken to the post's [timeline page](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/363052/timeline), which shows, among other things, when a post first became a hot network question.

Comment: Oh, that is new. Didn't saw it.

Comment: Indeed, it was added [just recently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342316/370674).

Answer (score 2):

Not as convenient, but another alternative is manually go to the URL.  This technically takes you to the Revisions page as you asked, and not the Timeline (both contain similar information though):

1. Take the post ID from the URL (outlined in red below)

[image: Post URL]

2. Type in your address bar `https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/{postId}/revisions` and it should take you to the [page](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/363052/revisions) regardless if any actual "edit" history has occurred.

Answer (score 1):

You can install the [Stack Overflow Extras (SOX)](https://stackapps.com/q/6091/10706) user script. One of its [features](https://github.com/soscripted/sox/wiki/Features) is:

> Add timeline and revision links to the bottom of each post for quick access to them